# Heart plus diamond is spade-and-club: table puzzle

Tags: code-golf, string

I found [this](https://youtu.be/ZYj4NkeGPdM?si=5kgpgIe8zDgfYZsK&t=2658) YouTube video with a table on it showing some card suits with ampersands. You might not understand what it is about, but I still want to make a challenge about it.

The input is two suits, being one of the following:

```
heart
diamond
spade
club
```

You can do anything for any other input.

Then the output is their 'game sum':

1. If both suits are red (heart/diamond), then:

   - Up to one heart promotes to a spade
   - Up to one diamond demotes to a club
2. Output in order of priority (spade > heart > diamond > club).

Leading and trailing whitespace is allowed.

Example input:

```
spade
heart
```

Example output:

```
spade and heart
```

Use any language. This is code-golf, so shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Is the output `club and spade` an acceptable alternative for `spade and club`, or does the order matter?

Comment: @Arnauld The order matters. "club and spade" is not an acceptable alternative for "spade and club".

Comment: Unless you provide some motivation, this looks like an arbitrary and somewhat boring task. If there is a rule or pattern that governs the input-output relationship, finding it out [should not](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19231/36398) be a part of the challenge

Comment: The video this question is based does not even provide any justification for this pattern, only showing this table briefly from what looks like a book.

Comment: If anyone is interested, you can find the chart on page 361 of Winning Ways, but I don't think any proof is given there either (though i do believe it has an actual mathematical meaning)

Comment: The order pf precedence (sorting order) Spade Heart Diamond Club is from the game Bridge (and is coincidentally reverse alphabetical order.) Cards stay the same unless both are red, in which case the first available heart is promoted to spade and the last available diamond is demoted to club. I've watched the video and it gives no clue why this should be the case.

Comment: These are loopy games in combinatorial game theory (similar to chess positions), and adding them is like playing with two boards, one with the first chess position and the other with the second.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 58 bytes

```
O^`
h.+¶[hd]
spade $&
[td]¶d.+
$& club
( .+)?¶(.+ )?
 and
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcxRDsIgDIDh956iD3NhIeEKO4IPPi4zQ0vCEkUzt6txAC6GsVJ4Kn/Tj83ta7D5pC4LGszn6wLe6BQnTzN83pYcdj1MO80pktHQ9Xh/HDdQaPQwpqiMxmEEtIEw5z/QyBOkGEjQap@vQLW9s9sOwKNKKZYSIqWLLOtqW7NuKb5tyg@/u8pLsC1vgSVZfQE) Takes input on separate lines but link is to test suite that splits on  `+`  for convenience. Explanation:

```
O^`
```

Sort in reverse order.

```
h.+¶[hd]
spade $&
```

Prefix `spade` if `heart` is followed by either `heart` or `diamond`.

```
[td]¶d.+
$& club
```

Suffix `club` if either `heart` or `diamond` are followed by `diamond`.

```
( .+)?¶(.+ )?
 and
```

Keep only the first and last words and join them with `and`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 33 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„‰áš¸#©¢O<i®“spade†Ú“#.;}{R„ €ƒÀý
```

Input as a pair of strings.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##AVYAqf9vc2FiaWX//@KAnuKAsMOhxaHCuCPCqcKiTzxpwq7igJxzcGFkZeKAoMOa4oCcIy47fXtS4oCeIOKCrMaSw4DDvf//WyJoZWFydCIsImRpYW1vbmQiXQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/a9UXJCYkqqQkZpYVKKQkpmYm5@XopCcU5qkpHx4cVmlvZLCo7ZJCkr2lS7/HzXMe9Sw4fDCowsP7VA@tPLQIn@bzEPrHjXMARvxqGHB4VlAjrKedW11EFCtwqOmNccmHW44vPe/zn8A).

**Explanation:**

```python
„‰áš¸                 # Push dictionary string "heart diamond"
     #                # Split it on spaces: ["heart","diamond"]
      ©               # Store this pair in variable `®` (without popping)
       ¢              # Count how many times each occurs in the (implicit) input-pair
        O             # Sum those counts together
         <i           # If it's 2:
                      # (this is only truthy for the following four pairs: dd,dh,hd,hh)
           ®          #  Push ["heart","diamond"] again from variable `®`
           “spade†Ú“  #  Push dictionary string "spade club"
                    # #  Split it on spaces as well: ["spade","club"]
           .;         #  Replace the first "heart" with "spade" and first "diamond"
                      #  with "club" in the (implicit) input-pair
          }           # Close the if-statement
                      # (the implicit else uses the implicit input-pair)
           {R         # Sort the pair in descending order (sort + reverse)
             „ €ƒ     # Push dictionary string "  and"
                 À    # Rotate it once to the left to " and "
                  ý   # Join the pair with " and " as delimiter
                      # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to use the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `„‰áš¸` is `"heart diamond"`; `“spade†Ú“` is `"spade club"`; and `„ €ƒ` is `"  and"`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

*-6 thanks to [@tsh](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/44718/tsh)*

Inspired by [Neil's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269117/58563).

Expects `([a, b])`.

```javascript
c=>(/[dt],h/.test([b,a]=c.sort())?"spade":a)+" and "+(/d,[dh]/.test(c)?"club":b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBToQwEIbvPMWEC21A8LyG3ZsvsEeWmNJ2dzFI11JMjPENTLx41PfwefYFfARsS2FFcQ90pvN/0/mZW/JAGirLg7qoBePdNu1oukRJxlQe7ZNY8UahrIhIntK4EVIhjFd@cyCM@wuCQx9IzcAPUcKijO1z10E1RKu28BcF7qioG1HxuBI7JPl9W0qO/G3j41hywq7Liq8fa4oucazEWsmy3iEjHSpCOUrQZh1i2ITQJymgOMTJLgJ0EwGJoIhAtEoLS3jyACquQPJGc1uUGTnHV7osuWplDQRC8N1X2Jja3HSYm8mRbU/Nq7CC4Ovz9fj@ps8AFhAcP14g0JAZeeU9Y9zZXehKH1MXzVZs5g26WcdENoVRZSW5E7r4E3C1kdlzItWEsBXP64U5Cz0w6M5Cfx0tDOqchQnw7/yhc87B8BMnxrkYCuOYE3Fycgb668YCnn1@zomVneo82PBbOzPdEcPo6SK/AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
c =>           // c[] = input array
(              //
  /[dt],h/     // if a is "heart" and b is
  .test(       // either "heart" or "diamond",
    [b, a] =   // where a and b are sorted such
      c.sort() // that a > b:
  ) ?          //
    "spade"    //   use "spade" as the left output
  :            // else:
    a          //   use a
) +            //
" and " +      // append " and "
(              //
  /d,[dh]/     // if b is "diamond" and a is
  .test(c) ?   // either "diamond" or "heart":
    "club"     //   use "club" as the right output
  :            // else:
    b          //   use b
)              //
```

Comment: 80 bytes if input as an array: `c=>(/[dt],h/.test([b,a]=c.sort())?"spade":a)+" and "+(/d,[dh]/.test(c)?"club":b)` or `c=>(/[dt],h/.test(c.sort())?"spade":c[1])+" and "+(/d,[dh]/.test(c)?"club":c[0])`

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 34 bytes

```
ṢṚµĖ41,3ḥⱮỊẸoḂƲȧ"ȯ"“ɓ¤PⱮ»Ḳ¤j“ and
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AVwAo/9qZWxsef//4bmi4bmawrXEljQxLDPhuKXisa7hu4rhurhv4biCxrLIpyLIryLigJzJk8KkUOKxrsK74biywqRq4oCcIGFuZCD///8iZGlhbW9uZCIsImhlYXJ0Ig)

- [Test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd846tPXINBNDHeOHO5Y@2rju4e6uh7t25D/c0XRs04nlSifWKz1qmHNy8qElAUDJQ7sf7th0aEkWUEghMS9F4f@jhrkPd047tITL2xokpmunABSxPtzOBeQl55QmAamUzMTc/LwUICsjNbGoBEgXFySmpIJ1Tjc63P6oaU3kfwA)

A full program that takes a single list of two strings and prints the result to STDOUT.

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for suggesting a technique that ultimately saved a byte!*

### Alternative [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 35 bytes

```
ṢṚµOḢ€ọ2¬Ẹo_J$ƲḂȧ"ȯ"“ɓ¤PⱮ»Ḳ¤j“ and
```

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AV0Aov9qZWxsef//4bmi4bmawrVP4bii4oKs4buNMsKs4bq4b19KJMay4biCyKciyK8i4oCcyZPCpFDisa7Cu@G4ssKkauKAnCBhbmQg////ImhlYXJ0IiwiZGlhbW9uZCI)

- [Test suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzkUPd846tNX/4Y5Fj5rWPNzda3RozcNdO/LjvVSObXq4o@nEcqUT65UeNcw5OfnQkoBHG9cd2v1wx6ZDS7KAQgqJeSkK/x81zH24c9qhJVze1iAxXTsFoIj14XYuIC85pzQJSKVkJubm56UAWRmpiUUlQLq4IDElFaxzutHhdqDNkf8B)

A full program that takes a single list of two strings and prints the result to STDOUT.

*Thanks to @JonathanAllan for pointing out a bug!*

This works because of the following pattern:

```
╔═══════════════════════════╦════╦═════╦═════╦═════╗
║ First character           ║ c  ║ d   ║ h   ║ s   ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Codepoint                 ║ 99 ║ 100 ║ 104 ║ 115 ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║ ọ2                        ║ 0  ║ 2   ║ 3   ║ 0   ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Subtract 1, or not, mod 2 ║ 1  ║ 1   ║ 0   ║ 1   ║
╠═══════════════════════════╬════╬═════╬═════╬═════╣
║ Subtract 2, or not, mod 2 ║ 1  ║ 0   ║ 1   ║ 1   ║
╚═══════════════════════════╩════╩═════╩═════╩═════╝
```

### Explanation

```
Ṣ                                    | Sort
 Ṛ                                   | Reverse
  µ                                  | Start a new monadic chain
   O                                 | Convert to codepoints
    Ḣ€                               | Head of each
      ọ2                             | Number of times divisible by 2
              Ʋ                      | Following as a monad:
        ¬Ẹ                           | - Any non-zero
          o_J$                       | - Or (the result of ọ2 from before minus the indices)
               Ḃ                     | Mod 2
                ȧ"                   | And zipped (with the reverse sorted input)
                  ȯ"“ɓ¤PⱮ»Ḳ¤         | Or zipped with "spade club" split at spaces
                            j“ and   | Join with " and " (the last ” is implicit)
```

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks. I’d made a mistake in the bit after the `ọ2` that I’d somehow failed to spot. Unfortunately I don’t think the corrected version easily supports your nice hash. I’ve found a hash that does work with this (using `Ė41,3ḥⱮỊẸoḂƲ`) which is one byte shorter so going with that!

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>52</s> 49 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υＳ⪫Ｅ⌈⟦υ⮌υ⟧⎇›⁼§hdκ§ι⁰⊙sc№Συλ§⪪spadeclub⁵κι and
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY5BSwNBDIXv/RXDnBJYQQqeehIRqSAUt7fiIe5Ed3B2ZpudlPbXT1NE8BB4efl4L8NIMhRKrX0VcbBGt9NlBO3cNs9a@yoxfwPiZrUzVeG1xAxvNNuc46QTHAx95xPLwqD4gZ3bs2SSC7wIU2WB56NSWuCxbnPgM/gx@M79GPjnxM7d423PF/DLYNenotbVW7yanxD/0f2cYjVupsBD0k/DH/A3MN447ygH5@3l1kKkqeSwGpmktrtTugI) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＳ
```

Input the two strings.

```
Ｅ⌈⟦υ⮌υ⟧⎇›⁼§hdκ§ι⁰⊙sc№Συλ§⪪spadeclub⁵κι and
```

Sort them in descending order, then unless one the two strings contains `s` or `c`, change the first string from `heart` to `spade` and the second from `diamond` to `club`, then join the results with `and`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 77 bytes

```perl
$,=" and ";/[dt] [dh]/&&s/heart/spade/+s/diamond/club/;say reverse sort/\S+/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY2xDsIgFEV3v@KFNF1q@@rQifQTnBxbY1CIbVKBAJr486I@YCHnkHvAKrcN8baYh@XWrTqAR0BoAF3H5jDOgfFY7UcGQktgHCcZzjDJ5Yx17XFRwgX0VkiFjUe5iofREm/b84rcizc49VLOK/Dmt5tPDd4jry7dWCGPlAGdu8T/LmN@Khv9s6MzB4kpSFiCZCnIdzkpRlGRkhVP4X@SK0JKiMqehMYfY8NqtI/tcej6Qx9b/QU)

Comment: Heart + Diamond is wrong; `/[dt] [dh]/` fixes it.

Comment: @Neil  Thanks!  I missed that when I reviewed my output.  Fixing it saved a few bytes, too.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), <s>76</s> 72 bytes

```
$"_ and _"⍜(⊟∩□|⊏⍖.)(∘|(⊙⊙;|⊙;)≍,,∩(("club"|"spade")=@h⊢),)×∩(∊:"hd"⊢),,
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_7_1__RiDihpAgJCJfIGFuZCBfIuKNnCjiip_iiKnilqF84oqP4o2WLiko4oiYfCjiipniipk7fOKKmTsp4omNLCziiKkoKCJjbHViInwic3BhZGUiKT1AaOKKoiksKcOX4oipKOKIijoiaGQi4oqiKSwsCuKGrzRfNF8zIOKKnijiioI64oqZ4oqC4pahIEYg4oipwrDilqEsLCkuIHsic3BhZGUiICJoZWFydCIgImRpYW1vbmQiICJjbHViIn0K)

Naïve solution to the problem (if anyone can golf this more, comment please)